# Сумма записей в sqlite

Tags: c, база-данных, sqlite

Пытаюсь записывать в последнюю колонку базы данных суму некоторых строк (`INT` и `REAL`), но не могу понять как их суммировать, нашел функции `sum()` и `total()`. Хочу суммировать `SCHEME_REPORT_FRACTION_1` и `SCHEME_REPORT_FRACTION_1`.

```
   dbOpenResult = openDatabase(databaseName);
char *sql = sqlite3_mprintf(
    "INSERT INTO '%q' "
        "('%q'"
        ",'%q'"
        ",'%q'"
        ",'%q'"
        ",'%q'"
        ",'%q'"
        ",'%q'"
        ",'%q'"
        ",'%q'"
        ",'%q'"
        ",'%q'"
        ",'%q'"
        ",'%q'"
        ",'%q'"
        ",'%q'"
        ",'%q'"
        ",'%q')"
    "VALUES ("
        "'%q'"
        ",'%q'"
        ",'%q'"
        ",'%q'"
        ",'%q'"
        ",'%q'"
        ",'%q'"
        ",'%q'"
        ",'%q'"
        ",'%q'"
        ",'%q'"
        ",'%q'"
        ",'%q'"
        ",'%q'"
        ",'%q'"
        ",'%q'"
        ", '%q'+'%q' );"
        , tableName
        , SCHEME_REPORT_RECIPE
        , SCHEME_REPORT_OPERATOR
        , SCHEME_REPORT_FRACTION_1
        , SCHEME_REPORT_FRACTION_2
        , SCHEME_REPORT_FRACTION_3
        , SCHEME_REPORT_FRACTION_4
        , SCHEME_REPORT_FRACTION_5
        , SCHEME_REPORT_FRACTION_6
        , SCHEME_REPORT_MP
        , SCHEME_REPORT_BITUMEN
        , SCHEME_REPORT_CELLULOSE_1
        , SCHEME_REPORT_CELLULOSE_2
        , SCHEME_REPORT_DUST
        , SCHEME_REPORT_MIXING_TIME
        , SCHEME_REPORT_TEMPERATURE
        , SCHEME_REPORT_TEMPERATURE_BITUMEN
        , SCHEME_REPORT_ASPHALT
        , strReport.recipe
        , strReport.operator
        , strReport.fraction_1
        , strReport.fraction_2
        , strReport.fraction_3
        , strReport.fraction_4
        , strReport.fraction_5
        , strReport.fraction_6
        , strReport.bitumen
        , strReport.mp
        , strReport.cellulose_1
        , strReport.cellulose_2
        , strReport.dust
        , strReport.mixing_time
        , strReport.temperature
        , strReport.temperature_bitumen
        , strReport.fraction_1
        , strReport.fraction_2);
```

*Код создания таблицы:*

```
char *sql = sqlite3_mprintf(
             "PRAGMA foreign_keys=on;"\
             "CREATE TABLE '%q'(" \
             "'%q'   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," \
             "'%q'   DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP," \
             "'%q'   TEXT," \
             "'%q'   TEXT," \
             "'%q'   INT," \
             "'%q'   INT," \
             "'%q'   INT," \
             "'%q'   INT," \
             "'%q'   INT," \
             "'%q'   INT," \
             "'%q'   REAL," \
             "'%q'   REAL," \
             "'%q'   REAL," \
             "'%q'   REAL," \
             "'%q'   INT," \
             "'%q'   INT," \
             "'%q'   INT," \
             "'%q'   INT," \
             "'%q'   INT);"
            , tableName
            , SCHEME_REPORT_ID
            , SCHEME_REPORT_TIME
            , SCHEME_REPORT_RECIPE
            , SCHEME_REPORT_OPERATOR
            , SCHEME_REPORT_FRACTION_1
            , SCHEME_REPORT_FRACTION_2
            , SCHEME_REPORT_FRACTION_3
            , SCHEME_REPORT_FRACTION_4
            , SCHEME_REPORT_FRACTION_5
            , SCHEME_REPORT_FRACTION_6
            , SCHEME_REPORT_BITUMEN
            , SCHEME_REPORT_MP
            , SCHEME_REPORT_CELLULOSE_1
            , SCHEME_REPORT_CELLULOSE_2
            , SCHEME_REPORT_DUST
            , SCHEME_REPORT_MIXING_TIME
            , SCHEME_REPORT_TEMPERATURE
            , SCHEME_REPORT_TEMPERATURE_BITUMEN
            , SCHEME_REPORT_ASPHALT);
```

Comment: функции sum используются при выборке с группировкой тут они ни к чему. вы моете написать просто `X+Y`. и кстати не понимаю, зачем заключать числовые данные в кавычки. И ... стоп, а почему какие то формулы в первой части insert где просто перечисляются колонки в которые идет вставка. что бы могло значить "вставить значение в сумму колонок". как вы себе представляете такую операцию

Comment: И собственно сумму каких строк вы хотите записать. insert values вставляет только одну строку, суммировать как бы нечего

Comment: " И ... стоп, а почему какие то формулы в первой части insert где просто перечисляются колонки в которые идет вставка" - это обычные строки, мне кажется лучше их хранить в одном месте что бы при потребности быстро изменить и не править весь код

Comment: ", '%q' + '%q')" - SQL error: near "+": syntax error

Comment: Я не про %q то что вы имена колонок подставляете из кода. У вас же выходит типа `insert into tab(x + y) values(5)` т.е. вы пытаетесь сказать БД "положи в сумму колонок x и y число 5". но как можно положить одно число в сумму колонок, что дложна сделать БД, поделить число 5 на 2 и положить в X=2.5 и в Y=2.5 ?

Comment: Не понимаю что вас не устраивает, бд работает но не могу сложить сумму некоторых полей и положить в последнее поле. Делал по данному примеру - ' INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME [(column1, column2, column3,...columnN)]  
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...valueN);'

Comment: В первой части insert пишется не что положить, а _куда_ положить. я бы понял если бы вы писали `insert into tab(x) values(5+10)` что означало бы положи в колонку 'x' сумму 5+10, т.е. положи число 15. но вы же пишите положи одно число, как то поделив его между _двумя_ разными колонками

Comment: Я начал понимать что вы хотите положить в какую то колонку сумму двух других из той же записи. но в какую колонку вы хотите положить эту сумму, как она называется ? вот в первой части insert пишется именно имя колонки в которую нужно положить значение, а уже в values при желании можете что то вычислять, но имена колонок там писать нельзя, потому что в них еще нет никаких значений, так что проще всего было бы сложить их перед вставкой, т.е. сложение писать не в sql-запросе, а когда вы значения перечисляете

Comment: Я вас понял.код подправил но в результате ASPHALT = 0 получаю

Comment: из вашего запроса не видно что такое  ASPHALT и как вы заносите в него значение. я это должен угадать ?

Comment: конечно там 0 будет. у вас `SCHEME_REPORT_FRACTION_1` чему равно ? думаю строке с названием колонки, с учетом кавычек которые вы зачем то продолжаете писать для числовых значений (чего делать на стоит) у вас выходит `... values(..., 'FRACTION_1'+'FRACTION_2')` что по вашему сделает SQL когда попытается сложить две _строки_ и положить это в числовое поле, странно почему 0, а не NULL. почему вы не пишите в конце вашего списка `strReport.fraction_1, strReport.fraction_2` ? т.е. значения колонок а не их названия

Comment: Заработало, огромное спасибо!